# How do i configure a repeater control to display data only of a particular element value with XmlDataSource?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

So before i start, this is some data from my xml file

```
    <item>
    <menuType>Lunch</menuType>
    <itemName>Sweet Caramel</itemName>
    <price>30</price>
    <preparationTime>20</preparationTime>
</item>
<item>
    <menuType>Dinner</menuType>
    <itemName>Cocoa Swirl Cheesecake</itemName>
    <price>9</price>
    <preparationTime>30</preparationTime>
</item>
<item>
    <menuType>Lunch</menuType>
    <itemName>Spanish Monkfish</itemName>
    <price>10</price>
    <preparationTime>30</preparationTime>
</item>
<item>
    <menuType>Dinner</menuType>
    <itemName>Ice Cream</itemName>
    <price>20</price>
    <preparationTime>10</preparationTime>
</item>
<item>
    <menuType>Lunch</menuType>
    <itemName>Complete Fruit Salad</itemName>
    <price>10</price>
    <preparationTime>15</preparationTime>
</item>
```

So my question is, how can i configure my repeater control to display only items which have a menuType value of 'Lunch'

Comment: Do you already have the XML deserialized?

Comment: what do you mean by deserialized? I don't know if this can be done using <itemTemplate> etc

Comment: How are you binding the data to the Repeater at the moment?

Comment: using an xmldataSource control

Comment: Can you post that also? Because in a repeater you can pretty much design the HTML like you want.

Comment: Please keep in mind, i'm working on visual studio and i'm doing this using visual basics. No hard coding as i work mostly in design view by dragging and dropping the dataSource controls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. You need to set the filter in the `XPath` property of the `XmlDataSource`. `XPath="/items/item[menuType='Lunch']"`

```
<asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlDataSource1" runat="server" DataFile="menuItems.xml" XPath="/items/item[menuType='Lunch']"></asp:XmlDataSource>

<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="XmlDataSource1">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# XPath("menuType") %>
        <br />
        <%# XPath("itemName") %>
        <br />
        <%# XPath("price") %>
        <br />
        <%# XPath("preparationTime") %>
        <hr />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to print anything out hmm and where did the 'items' in the XPath property of the XmlDataSource come from? there's no element called items. just 'item'

Comment: i just needed 2 slashes at the begining. Probable because of my software version